# FHIR: Treating identifier.value as an integer for matching

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there any way to instruct the server to use integer matching when searching an identifier (ignore leading zeros)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Because in some environments, leading zeros would be significant.  Your best bet would be to define a normalization convention for that particular NamingSystem that says that leading zeros must be removed before transmission (just as we say you must remove the dashes from social security numbers, for example).